# Как обработать json с сервера на unity3d?

Tags: unity3d

Добрых суток.
Не могу найти как организовать обмен данными по websocket в юнити в json-формате.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Как подключить вебсокет я разобрался, но вот как обработать поступившее сообщение которое находится в стандартном json-формате я не могу найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Unity есть специальная утилита ([JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html)) для работы с джейсонами.
Вам нужен её метод *FromJson*, который примет присланную вам через сокет строку и вернёт нужный вам класс (ну, или попытается это сделать).

```
string json = //тут вы формирует его из полученных байтов
MyClass class = JsonUtility.FromJson<MyClass>(json);

if (class != null)
{
    class.DoCool("Мы сделали это!");
}
else
{
    LogService.PushError("Где json, Лебовски?!");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Серверная часть на другом языке написана. А этот класс, как я понял, занимается сериализацией юнитивских объектов.

Comment: Мне бы просто распарсить в обычные объекты вроде строк да словарей. А из этого уже можно будет и объекты создать. Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: @МистерФикс, эта утилита пытается превратить json в конкретный класс. Не имеет особо значения каким образом этот json был получен, главное, чтобы вы пытались превратить его в структуру, в которой такие же имена и типы у сериализуемых полей

Comment: Мысль понял. Буду разбираться, спасибо.